# Android: add permissions to push out notifications

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and I plan to push out notifications to the user in a *future* version. However, I want to add the permissions for it already on the current version.

How do I do this?

For example, in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, should I add something like:

```
<permission
    android:name="...permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="...permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [GCM permission](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest)

```
<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

is correct. **BUT**

> You should not add any permission into manifest, which your app is not
>   using. Better to add permission in the same version when you will
>   introduce PUSH notification feature.